# Prevent Mac From Reloading Apps After Restart

Tags: macos, mac, boot, osx-lion

I had to power cycle my Macbook Pro by holding down the power button after it locked up.

When it restarted, it reloaded all the apps that I had been running before, which took a long time and was completely unnecessary.

Is there a way I can prevent it from reloading the previously running apps?

I'm running OS X 10.7.

Answer (score 9):

Holding the shift key down at login should prevent apps from relaunching for that login.

If you want to permanently prevent apps from reopening, you can quit all apps then lock the `com.apple.loginwindow.*.plist` file found in `~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/`

This plist keeps a list of open apps, and any apps that are in that list at logout will be launched again after login (assuming the checkbox is ticked to do so, as it always is by default). If you quit all apps, then lock that plist, it's list of apps will always be empty, so even when that checkbox is ticked, there will be no apps in the list to relaunch.

Unlocking the plist will return it to normal behavior.

Comment: Apart from **Terminal** — You need to have Terminal open to lock the file. But just having Terminal open is still a huge improvement.

Comment: How do you lock the file?

Answer (score 9):

What you are looking for is to disable ApplePersistence feature, which can be done with:

```
defaults write -g ApplePersistence -bool no
```

Comment: Note that this will disable Versions as well.

Comment: @Brady what are 'Versions'? what impact should I expect if I use `defaults write -g ApplePersistence -bool no`?

Comment: @olyv Versions in the file system. See here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27544/how-to-completely-disable-auto-save-and-versions-in-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: @Brady thanks, I get it now. And this is a link to Apple docs https://support.apple.com/en-ie/HT202255

Comment: The Apple support article link is now dead.

Comment: @2540625 https://web.archive.org/web/20160617161645/support.apple.com/en-ie/HT202255

Answer (score 3):

First ***close*** all applications (this is important). Then in a terminal do:

```
sudo chown root ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.loginwindow*
sudo chmod 000 ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.loginwindow*
```

Basically, you need to make the loginWindow* files unwritable by anyone.

To **undo**:

```
sudo rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.loginwindow*
```

Comment: best solution here

Comment: Isn't a Terminal an application? (☞ ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)☞

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Preferences/General.

Un-click the box "Restore windows when quitting..."

Comment: That'll prevent an app from reopening windows when it starts, but it's completely separate from the feature that reopens apps at login.